# How do I combine both of these scripts into one?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an extension in which both work together on Tampermonkey, but I wish to combine both of them into one single script instead. When I do try to combine both, only one of the two functions will work instead of both. How would I combine so both will work in one single script?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @version      0.03
// @license      MIT
// @match        http://agar.io/*
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
var amount = 6;
var duration = 50; //ms

var overwriting = function(evt) {
for (var i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.onkeydown({keyCode: 87}); // KEY_W
        window.onkeyup({keyCode: 87});
    }, i * duration);
}
};

window.addEventListener('mousedown', overwriting);

})();
```

Here is the second script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include http://agar.io/*
// @include https://agar.io/*
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
(function(){
$.getScript("https://googledrive.com/host/0B-pE6yLMAbwMX1FSaWFXV3gyZGc");
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem are the two UserScript-blocks. Basically you need to combine them. 
But maybe you can get away with putting the second script before the first one, since it includes (almost) everything the first one defines.

And maybe you may also need to copy the `@run-at` definition over.